# When restart Hadoop Yarn does that affect the running MapReduce Jobsthat

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop-yarn

A few times I restarted Yarn when there were running MapReduce jobs on it, but I found that the running MR jobs were not affected. i.e after restarting Yarn, the MR jobs could be resumed immediately, I was wondering that why didn't the MR jobs failed? btw, all of my MapReduce jobs were Pig script job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html) provides the HA(High availability) architecture of YARN's Resource Manager.

In your case , I believe Automatic fail over is enabled ,so when the Resource Manager goes down , another RM is automatically elected to be the active.